# Valgrind use of unitialised value

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I am creating a symbol table for a compiler I am writing and when I try adding to my symbol table I keep getting valgrind errors. When I call my function, I am calling my add function

```
stAdd (&sSymbolTable, "test", RSRVWRD, 4, 9);
```

and in my stAdd function it is currently

```
void stAdd (StPtr psSymbolTable, char *identifier, SymbolTableType type,
    int addressField, int arrayDimensions)
{
  int hashValue;

  hashValue = hash (identifier, psSymbolTable->numBuckets);

  if (psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue] == NULL)
  {
    psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue] = (StEntryPtr) malloc (sizeof(StEntry));
    strcpy (psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->identifier, identifier);
    psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->entryLevel = psSymbolTable->currentLevel;
    psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->type = type;
    psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->addressField = addressField;
    psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->arrayDimensions = arrayDimensions;
    psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->psNext = NULL;
  }
}
```

But every time I set a value within my StEntry struckt, I get an error

> Use of unitialised value of size 8

every time I set something within the if statement. Does any see where I am going wrong?

My StEntry is

```
 typedef struct StEntry
{
  char identifier[32];
  SymbolTableLevel entryLevel;
  SymbolTableType type;
  int addressField;
  int arrayDimensions;
  StEntryPtr psNext;
} StEntry;
```

Comment: Does `valgrind` not give you the line number?  It should if you compiled the code with `-g` (and if you didn't do that, you darn well should because you're throwing away a lot of the usefulness of `valgrind` if it can't tell you the line numbers).  Which line does it point at?  What's the complete message?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There are 8 total errors, pointing too each line from the if statement down

Comment: If one of the lines pointed at is the `if` statement, you have problems with the way your `spSymbolTable` array is (not) initialized.  You should probably be using `calloc()`, or looping through the array and setting each entry to NULL when you first allocate it.  Note that `malloc()` is not guaranteed to zero the memory.  Things go downhill from there, it seems.  At least you've got `valgrind` to point out the errors of your ways.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when I create my spSymbolTable, I look through all the indices and do `psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[i] = NULL;` if that makes anything clearer

Comment: I think there's some difference between what your claims and `valgrind`'s claims. Without intending to offend you, I trust `valgrind` over you at this stage. Please review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  In this context, it could be a symbol table with one bucket and a hash function that always returns 0.  If you can then show that the single call to `stAdd()` still runs into the problem, we have something to work on. Please include the entire `valgrind` message for the first of the errors in the MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot easier if I could see the definition of `struct StEntry` or even the precise valgrind error. But I'll take a wild guess anyway, because I'm feeling overconfident.

Here, you `malloc`  a new `StEntry` which you will proceed to fill in:

```
psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue] = (StEntryPtr) malloc (sizeof(StEntry));
```

This is C, by the way. You don't need to cast the result of the malloc, and it is generally a good idea not to do so. Personally, I'd prefer:

```
StEntry* new_entry = malloc(sizeof *new_entry);
// Fill in the fields in new_entry
psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashvale] = new_entry;
```

And actually, I'd ditch the hungarian prefixes, too, but that's an entirely other discussion, which is primarily opinion-based. But I digress.

The next thing you do is:

```
strcpy (psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->identifier, identifier);
```

Now, `psSymbolTable->spSymbolTable[hashValue]->identifier` might well be a `char *`, which will point to the character string of the identifier corresponding to this symbol table entry. So it's a pointer. But what is its value? Answer: it doesn't have one. It's sitting in a block of malloc'd and uninitialized memory.

So when `strcpy` tries to use it as the address of a character string... well, watching out for the flying lizards. (If that's the problem, you could fix it in a flash by using `strdup` instead of `strcpy`.)

Now, I could well be wrong. Maybe the `identifier` member is not `char*`, but rather `char[8]`. Then there is no problem with what it points to, but there's also nothing stopping the `strcpy` from writing beyond its end. So either way, there's something ungainly about that line, which needs to be fixed.

Comment: My identifier is an array instead of a char *. I have added my definition of my StEntry struct.

Comment: @john: Ok. Then  you should replace strcpy with strncpy (but what are you going to tell people who like 32-character identifiers?)

Comment: @rici: raw `strncpy()` isn't the solution; it doesn't always null terminate the string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, but it's a start; it doesn't overwrite the next field, either. I'm actually lobbying for `strdup` (or equivalent thereto).